Python: Combining Multiple Worksheets into One
What I'm trying to do is combine different Excel worksheet exports into one. I'm using one file as the "base_file" and then adding to that. Some columns from the new worksheets match and some don't. For the columns that match from the new file to the base I am asking the code to just add the new data to the end, and for the columns that do not match, I am asking the code to add those new columns and then add the data in for the new rows. It's working to an extent. For example the first screenshot is from the output file and the second is from the raw data, some of the values match (cost, impression) but then others are missing. Maybe I'm doing my concatenation wrong, but cannot figure it out.
First Screenshot:

Second Screenshot (Original Data):

Code:
base_file = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/base_file.xlsx")

additional_files = [
    "C:/Users/File_1.xlsx",
    "C:/UsersFile_2.xlsx"
    "C:/Users/File_3.xlsx",
    ]

for file in additional_files:
    # Load the new file
    new_file = pd.read_excel(file)
    
    common_columns = base_file.columns.intersection(new_file.columns)
    
    new_file_common = new_file[common_columns]
    base_file = pd.concat([base_file, new_file_common.reindex(columns=base_file.columns)], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort = False)
    
    new_columns = new_file.columns.difference(base_file.columns)
    
    # Add new columns to the base file with NaN values for existing rows
    for col in new_columns:
        base_file[col] = pd.NA
    
    # Append the data for new columns, ensuring alignment by index
    new_file_non_common = new_file[new_columns]
    base_file = pd.concat([base_file, new_file_non_common.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1, sort = False)
    
    # Remove any duplicated columns
    base_file = base_file.loc[:,~base_file.columns.duplicated()]

with pd.ExcelWriter('final_combined_file_corrected1.xlsx') as writer:
    # Write the combined DataFrame to the first sheet
    base_file.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Combined Data', index=False)


Just a clarification, do you want to merge multiple single worksheet files or is it potentially the case the each file has multiple sheets and you want to merge everything into a final single file single sheet?

I want to merge the data from different worksheets into one single worksheet. Combining all the data into one worksheet. @JonSG

You seem to be confusing workbook (aka file) and worksheet. A workbook can contain multiple worksheets.

are you concatenating files, or do the files have common indices so that some columns need to be added to others columns for the same row? If not, and you just concat, you can simply use pd.concat and it will concat files with different columns without any issue.

Yes so these are different workbooks and they all have one worksheet. I'm concatenating the files. Some of the files have the same column names so for those I want the data added to those columns just in new rows and the columns that don't exist in the base file to be added at the end with their data added to new rows

ok, so ,read all the files, and just use pd.concat. It does exactly that for you. you will get NaNs in all the cells that are not present. You can then fillna with whatever you need.

Concatenating all the files with pandas.concat will do all you need.
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,4,6]], columns=['a', 'b','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[6,8,10], [8,10,12]], columns=['b', 'c', 'd'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])


